# Disable Browser autocomplete but allow remote data autocomplete

Tags: html, jquery, input, autocomplete

Is there any way to disable the browser autocomplete when using autocomplete with remote data?

What I do is retrieving user name from our Active Directory GAL (Global Address List).
with this jQuery function. it works perfectly but when you start typing in the text field, Chrome will display its own suggestion above the list of username, you need to close that windows to be able to select the username from the returned list.

If I disable autocomplete it will disable obviously both, so is there any parameter or option I could use to disable only Chrome/Edge autocomplete suggestion?

```js
function initAutoComplete(textbox, textboxEmail) {
  $(function() {
    //$(textbox).disableAutoFill();
    $(textbox).autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/Gal/AutocompleteUsers/',
          data: {
            "term": request.term
          },
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            response($.map(data, function(item) {
              return {
                label: item.givenName + " " + item.lastName,
                email: item.email
              };
            }));
          },
          error: function(response) {
            alert('error' + response);
          },
          failure: function(response) {
            alert('failure');
          }
        });
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        if (textbox == '.gal') {
          $(this).closest("tr").find(textboxEmail).val(ui.item.email);
        } else {
          $(textboxEmail).val(ui.item.email);
        }
      },
      minLength: 2
    });
  })
};
```

Comment: You can disable autocomplete from the browser and still have your JS function.

Comment: Just add `autocomplette="off"` to the form field(s)

Comment: But please remove  `$(function() {` from the function - it means "when page loads" and that has already happened when you run your function